# Excel auto-increment not working

Tags: excel, reference, increment, excel-indirect

I'm trying to use INDIRECT to pull a sheet name from my master list 'SheetList' which contains a list of all sheet names in column A, eg. A1, A2, A3, A4.

I've used INDIRECT to pull this sheet name out, and then reference the same cell position for each sheet.

```
=INDIRECT("'"&INDIRECT("SheetList" & "!A1")&"'!C23")
=INDIRECT("'"&INDIRECT("SheetList" & "!A2")&"'!C23")
=INDIRECT("'"&INDIRECT("SheetList" & "!A3")&"'!C23")
```

However when I select these, and try and increment it using the cross, it goes back to A1

```
=INDIRECT("'"&INDIRECT("SheetList" & "!A1")&"'!C23")
=INDIRECT("'"&INDIRECT("SheetList" & "!A2")&"'!C23")
=INDIRECT("'"&INDIRECT("SheetList" & "!A3")&"'!C23")
=INDIRECT("'"&INDIRECT("SheetList" & "!A1")&"'!C23")
```

Why doesn't it increment to A4? I'm really confused.

Comment: Perhaps because the A1 is within quotes, ie. Excel considers it to be text, not a cell reference to be modified as you cut-and-paste (using the cross).

Answer (score 1):

As dave mentioned in his comment, you've hard coded the reference to the SheetList cell by putting it between double quotes. Update as follows, removing one of the `INDIRECT`:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&SheetList!A1&"'!C23")
```

Comment: Then you should accept @nutsch's answer so he gets the kudos ;)